# Centering Formspree.io input fields in React

Tags: css, reactjs

All!

I have been working on adding a Formspree.io contact form to my React app. However, I have been having trouble getting the  fields to center. You can see from the code I have been able to center the text no problem, but the input fields simply will not center.

Here is the code;

```
import React from 'react';



export default class MyForm extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
     this.state = {
       status: ""
     };
   }

   render() {
     const { status } = this.state;
     return (
      <section id="contact">
       <form
         onSubmit={this.submitForm}
         action="https://formspree.io/xzbzkopq"
         method="POST"
       >
          <br></br> 
         <h3>Use this contact form to reach out and I will get back to you as soon as possible!</h3>
         <div>
         <label>Email:</label>
         <input class="email" type="email" name="email" />
         <label>Message:</label>
         <input class="message" type="text" name="message" />
         {status === "SUCCESS" ? <p>Success! I will get back to you soon!</p> : <button>Submit</button>}
         {status === "ERROR" && <p>Ooops! There was an error. Try submitting the form again or reaching out to me directly at Contact@samkautz.com</p>}
         </div>
       </form>
       </section>
     );
   }

   submitForm(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     const form = ev.target;
     const data = new FormData(form);
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open(form.method, form.action);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
     xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
       if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
       if (xhr.status === 200) {
         form.reset();
         this.setState({ status: "SUCCESS" });
       } else {
         this.setState({ status: "ERROR" });
       }
     };
     xhr.send(data);
   }
 }
```

And the CSS;

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
/* h. Contact Section
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */

#contact {
   background: #191919;
   padding-top: 40px;
   padding-bottom: 100px;
   color: white;
   height: 600px;
}

#contact-input {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#contact h3 {
   font: 18px/24px 'opensans-bold', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   color: #EBEEEE;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
}

#contact .section-head { margin-bottom: 42px; }

#contact a, #contact a:visited  { color: #11ABB0; }
#contact a:hover, #contact a:focus { color: #fff; }

#contact h1 {
   font: 18px/24px 'opensans-bold', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   color: #EBEEEE;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#contact h1 span { display: none; }
#contact h1:before {
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   content: "\f0e0";
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 72px;
   line-height: 72px;
   text-align: left;
   float: left;
   color: #ebeeee;
}

#contact h4 {
   font: 16px/24px 'opensans-bold', sans-serif;
   color: #EBEEEE;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
}
#contact p.lead {
   font: 18px/36px 'opensans-light', sans-serif;
   padding-right: 3%;
}
#contact .header-col { padding-top: 6px; }


/* Twitter Feed */
#twitter {
   margin-top: 12px;
   padding: 0;
}
#twitter li {
   margin: 6px 0px 12px 0;
   line-height: 30px;
}
#twitter li span {
   display: block;
}
#twitter li b a {
   font: 13px/36px 'opensans-regular', Sans-serif;
   color: #474747 !important;
   border: none;
}
```

If anyone has any advice on how I can get these  fields to center I would be very grateful! Thanks in advance for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class='inputWrapper'>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input class="email" type="email" name="email" />
    <label>Message:</label>
    <input class="message" type="text" name="message" />
    {status === "SUCCESS" ? <p>Success! I will get back to you soon!</p> : <button>Submit</button>}
    {status === "ERROR" && <p>Ooops! There was an error. Try submitting the form again or reaching out to me directly at Contact@samkautz.com</p>}
</div>


.inputWrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Is this what you want?
By the way, use class rather than id would be better.

Comment: Thanks Hong! I actually ended up wrapping each <label> and <input> in its own div and using your css and it came out perfect!